# hibernate ORM -Caching queries

Tags: quarkus

I was testing the cache query feature of hibernate orm extension but I'm getting strange results looking at statistics:

- Configuring a query with hint `org.hibernate.cacheable = true` does nothing (The query is always executed
- For it to work, I have to define my entity as `@Cacheable`. Like this, the second time I call the query, I don't see it executed and only get the results

My question is:

Documentation seems to state that query cache is independent from entity cache. My point is, what are the implications of defining the entity Cacheable?

Will it affect only query by ID?

Can this be a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, this is the regular behaviour of Hibernate ORM:

When running an entity query there's two aspects at play:

1. Caching the query -> which IDs of object to return
2. Caching each object - by ID

You can opt to cache 1 or 2, or both - depending on what you need.

Documented [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching-query); see in particular the info note after the examples.

Comment: The problem I see is that, if I chosse option 1) (Caching query) without defining the entity as Cacheable, I can see the put on cache after the query execution but repeating the same query will not get results from cache but again from the database.
I don't see in the documentation any reference that requires an entity to be Cacheable for the query cache to work.